# Can I use directsound on VS2010 with C# on Window8 OS?

Tags: c#, windows-8, directx, directsound

I tried to install the xna 4.0 but there was some error on windows8.

Which version of Directx SDK can I use for C#?

I also tried to install the DXSDK_Jun10, however I could not find any reference in .net folder.

Answer (score 0):

By the sound of it, you are relatively new to DirectX development with C#. Which is good news, as you are about to embark on a great journey!

It also means that you are currently best of using an intermediate library that gets the API stuff sorted for you, like the awesome [SlimDX](http://slimdx.org/).

Comment: If you are going to recommend libraries for DirectX on .NET, then you should at least mention [SharpDX](http://sharpdx.org/), it seems that SlimDX has not heard about them at all. (SharpDX is the library on which [MonoGame](http://monogame.codeplex.com) relies for DirectX access - MonoGame adds real cross-platform game development to the mix, but it might be overkill if you are only targeting Windows)